# Adding points of map as one layer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I'm adding points from a json file using the following approach:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(places.features)      
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr('cx', function(d) { d.geometry.coordinates)[0]})
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return proj(d.geometry.coordinates)[1]})  
  .attr("r", function(d) { 
      if (d.properties.category == 'a'){           
        return 2
      }else if (d.properties.category == 'b'){            
        return 4
      }else if (d.properties.category == 'c'){            
        return 6
      }
    });
```

I have been tweaking the map in Adobe Illustrator, and I realize that I am not adding the points as a group to the map; instead each point is an individual layer due to how I constructed this. How can I add the points as one layer group instead?

I constructed the `svg` and `proj` in the following way:

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 900,
    radius = 340; 

var proj = d3.geo.naturalEarth()    
    .scale(200) 
    .translate([width / 2 , height/2])

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(proj);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Place them in a group:

```
svg.append('g').selectAll("circle")
  .data(places.features)
  .enter()
```

Comment: I see - that explains the `g`! Thank you. Is it possible to both use the `g` group and still preserve the style such that this is visible in Illustrator? When I group I seem to loose all styles that I set within D3.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never used illustrator! From this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/5qtWdOGFCBM 
you might want to try inkscape instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [SVG `<g>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups) for grouping graphics elements together.  The "g" doesn't have any visual representation of it's own.  It's only purpose is to group other elements.